# how to concat year =2019 and period=6 to give 20106 and not 20196 number and year =2018 , period=3112 to give 20183112

Tags: sql, oracle, join, concatenation, sybase

i need to join two tables  based on tiemperiod .
 such that 
table1.dateperiod =table2.(combination of period and year)
i.e 201906=201906     (year 2019 month is 6  both integers)
i.e 20183112=20183112

the problem is how to concat them while period is 6 and such that after concatenating it will be 201906 and not 20196
and

table 1

```
ID  NAME    DATE_PERIOD
1   conan   201906
1   conan   202012
1   conan   20183112
2   andy    201903
```

table2

```
ID  PROFILE YEAR    PERIOD
1   host    2019    6
1   writer  2018    3112
1   anchor  2020    12
2   sidekic 2019    3
```

please refer this db fiddle -[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=adf8e2e1dc1caccae9c60a952da9cfb9)

```
select
 *
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.date_period= (t2.year*100+t2.period)
```

expected solution

```
ID  PROFILE YEAR    MONTH   ID  NAME    DATE_PERIOD
1   anchor  2020    12  1   conan   202012
1   host    2019    6   1   conan   201906
1   sidekick    2020    12  1   andy    202003
1   writer  2018    3112    1   conan   20183112
```

Comment: Sybase or Oracle? Those are two very different database products

Answer (score 1):

If they're both *integer* data types, you should be able to construct the six-digit variant from year and month by just using:

```
year * 100 + month
```

If they're character data types, Oracle provides an `lpad` function for just this purpose, something like:

```
concat(year, lpad(month, 2, '0'))
```

Sybase, on the other hand, can use `replicate` to do padding but it's much uglier, something like:

```
year || replicate('0', (2 - char_length(month))) || month
```

Not sure *which* one you want since you gave *both* tags.

---

And re your edit, where the month may also hold `DDMM` format, you can simply use modulo arithmetic to get the final two characters. I won't bother looking up the function for that in Oracle/Sybase, I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. Suffice to say `3112 mod 100` is `12`.

Comment: i am so sorry . but there was a slight change in the input . i edited the question and fiddle . the month column is also giving combined date and month like "ddmm" format . provide a solution.thanks for your contribution .

Comment: hi i dont need month from ddmm. that is to say if we have 2018 and 3112 . i need 2018312 . or year 2017 and period=610 then i need 20170610

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LPAD` as follows:

```
select
 *
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 
on t1.id = t2.id and t1.date_period= concat(year,LPAD(month,2,0))
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=60a27ecdac3d3c0c25e6fefae85649e9)

**--UPDATE--**

You can use `CASE` statement as follows:

```
select
 *
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id 
and t1.date_period =  concat(year,
                             LPAD(period,
                                  case when length(period) <= 2 
                                       then 2 
                                       else 4 
                                   end,
                                   0))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=43e5426ce16b24eecde1be37aa9e63f4)

Comment: i am so sorry . but there was a slight change in the input . i edited the question and fiddle . the month column is also giving combined date and month like "ddmm" format . provide a solution.thanks for your contribution

Comment: i am so sorry .i should have given all the possible scenrios ahead.

Comment: when year2017 and period =611  that is i need 20170611 but this sql is not satisfying this condition

Comment: simply put i have data which omitted zero at first place.so, 2018, 3112 ineed 20183112. if 2017 ,208 i need 20170208

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to handle cases where the length of period is lesser or greater than four

```
    select
       *
       from table2 t2,table1 t1 
       where t1.id = t2.id 
           and t1.date_period =  concat(year,
                         LPAD(period,
                   decode(length(period),1,2,3,4,length(period))
                               ,
                               0));
```